# Is the “VistaBridge” compatible with Windows XP?

Tags: wpf, add-in, wpftoolkit

I'm wondering if [VistaBridge](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge) is compatible with Windows XP? I'm running Windows 7 so I can't test it. 
Have you tried it on Windowx XP? Please let me know.

Nam.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, because I imagine VistaBridge just exposes new functions and features in the Vista/7 native APIs, rather than re-implementing them.

Comment: Sorry for my naive. Please explain more. I don't get why exposing features of Vista/7 APIs for dotNet framework will not make the dotNet application compatible in XP? 

And moreover, what is the diffences between exposing and re-implementing?

Comment: If you are careful, the .NET program will still be compatible with XP, however, the new features in Vista/7 will not be available. A lot of the .NET Framework, especially Windows.Forms, is actually just a layer on top of the Windows non-.NET DLLs, rather than the functionality being actually written in .NET. This also means that functions from newer Windows versions won't be available on older versions of the DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows 7 "XP Mode" this runs a virtual XP PC on your machine:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Or you could use any other Virtual PC:

Virtual PC:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en

VirtualBox:
http://www.virtualbox.org/

VMWare:
http://www.vmware.com/